# Having trouble loading a Listview on a Fragment called from a Navigation menu item

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

i am new into android programming. I am having difficulty showing a Listview on a ListFragment. I've already tried it on an activity and it worked perfectly, however,i tried displaying the same listview on a Listfragment called from a Navigation Drawer but my app crashes on item click. I have been on it for so long, tried getting answers from different websites but all to no avail.

Pls: A little help would be nice and much appreciated

The error displayed on the logcat is:

```
09-18 14:35:53.285
3602-3602/com.example.ceede.classwork E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.ceede.classwork, PID: 3602       
java.lang.NullPointerException at                                     
com.example.ceede.classwork.MainActivity.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:92)
at
android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:152)
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.ceede.classwork.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="android.support.v4.app.ListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.ceede.classwork;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<SingleRow> list;
    Context context;

    CustomAdapter(Context context) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        this.context = context;
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        String[] titles = res.getStringArray(R.array.Titles);
        int[] images = {R.drawable.admisntrationicon, R.drawable.articon, R.drawable.businesseducationicon,
                R.drawable.homeicon, R.drawable.drivericon, R.drawable.stafficon,
                R.drawable.counciloricon, R.drawable.physicalcon, R.drawable.englishicon,
                R.drawable.mathsicon, R.drawable.scienceicon, R.drawable.historyicon,
                R.drawable.suporticon};

        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            list.add(new SingleRow(titles[i], images[i]));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return list.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        SingleRow temp = list.get(i);
        View row = null;
        if(view==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row,viewGroup,false);
        }

        TextView titles= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textAdmin);
        ImageView image= (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.adminImage);

        return row;
    }
}
```

**SingleRow.java**

```
class SingleRow {

    public String titles;
    public int images;

    SingleRow(String titles, int images) {
        this.titles = titles;
        this.images = images;
    }
}
```

**MyFragmentClass.java**

```
package com.example.ceede.classwork;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MyFirstFragment extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_fragment,container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ListView listView= (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getActivity()));


    }

    public static Fragment newInstance() {

        MyFirstFragment frag=new MyFirstFragment();

        return frag;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.ceede.classwork;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

FragmentManager manager;
FragmentTransaction transaction;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.contact) {
        // Handle the camera action
        //Line 92. This is the Line of code causing the error
        FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, MyFirstFragment.newInstance());
        transaction.commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Your logcat shows that the NPE occurs in `MainActivity.java` line 92. The code you provided for **MainActivity.java** include only 83 lines... Please correct this and show us where the error occurs (e.g. insert a comment in the MainActivity code).

Comment: @gus42 I have edited the code and also commented on the line of code flagging the error. (Line 92), however, i am still getting the same error.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should not initialize `FragmentManager` and call `beginTransaction` in `onCreate`. `beginTransaction` and `commit` should be paired. If `onNavigationItemSelected` is called twice you run into trouble when the transaction is already committed.

Better use it this way:

```
if (id == R.id.contact) {
    FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
    // Handle the camera action
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, MyFirstFragment.newInstance());
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_fragment,container,false);
    ListView listView= (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getActivity()));

    return view;
}
```

The problems is that your listview is attached to Fragment and not to Activity.